# jquery remove or set null property in object after randomly chosen

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to remove or mark property question[i] null after the question is picked out of the object pool

```
var pool = {
        question1: {
            question: "This is question number 1",
            options: ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4"],
            answer: 0,
            used: false /*I add this to mark if this question is used but it doesn't work*/
        },
        question2: {
            question: "This is question number 2",
            options: ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4"],
            answer: 1,
            used: false
        },
        question3: {
            question: "This is question number 3",
            options: ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4"],
            answer: 2,
            used: false
        },
...
};
```

Logic: a question is randomly picked out of the pool. Then the question is removed or set as null so user won't see the same question again (unless the game is reset).

I've tried using `delete object.property` but it doesn't work: the question is still there and generated. Also, I've added a property: `used = false` (above) and set `used = true` when the question is chosen, then use if statement to filter it, but it still doesn't work.

```
function randomQuest(obj) {
        var keys = Object.keys(obj);
        return obj[keys[Math.floor(Math.random() * keys.length)]];
    }

function nextQuest() {
        currentQuest = randomQuest(pool);
        $(".question").html(currentQuest.question);

        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            $(".options").append("<div class='option'>" + currentQuest.options[i] + "</div>");
        }

        $(".option").on("click", checkAnswer);

        //TO DO: filter used question
        // I've added the code below here but they don't work
    }
```

Attempt 1: `delete pool.currentQuest;`
Attempt 2:

```
if (!currentQuest.used) {
            $(".question").html(currentQuest.question);
        }
        else {
            currentQuest = randomQuest(pool);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing `delete pool.currentQuest` does nothing since `pool` does not have a property called `currentQuest`. It has properties `question1` through `question3`.

You need to keep track of which question property you retrieved and then delete that (i.e. by `delete pool[myVarThatContainsTheQuestPropertyName]`).

Personally I would have an array of questions as my pool like so:

`var pool = [{id: 1, question: "", answers: []}, {...}]`

Then you could remove a question by something like `pool = pool.filter(function(q) { return q.id !== currentQuest.id })`

Comment: Thank you so much jlaitio. You solution works perfectly.